# Linux kernel - Number of CPUs limit

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu

I was browsing the Linux kernel code these days and I was hit by many questions about the possible number of CPUs supported by the kernel.

As I understand, the kernel, according to the arch, can handle a certain number of CPUs. This number is specified in the Kconfig file and is passed to the CONFIG_NR_CPUS option.

Here is my dmesg output:

`setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:5120 nr_cpumask_bits:240 nr_cpu_ids:240 nr_node_ids:1
 RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=5120 to nr_cpu_ids=240`

My questions are:

- why the `NR_CPUS` is this large ?
- where does the 240 `nr_cpumask_bits` and `nr_cpu_ids` come from ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: How many physical and logical cores do you _actually_ have on the system?

Answer (score 3):

> why the NR_CPUS is this large ?

Because there are real Linux systems with CPU counts on that order. I've seen actual test results for 1024 CPU machines.

I don't mean clusters of independent small systems, I mean single computers with that many CPU cores, all running a single Linux kernel.

For example, [SGI currently has](http://www.sgi.com/products/servers/) a system capable of scaling up to 32 CPU sockets. With today's max core count of 22 in Intel's Xeon line, that gets you to 704 cores, then double that with [Hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading). Between the time of this writing and the time you read this, that core limit will probably have been exceeded.

> where does the 240 nr_cpumask_bits and nr_cpu_ids come from ?

Probably some limit of your actual hardware. It takes a specially-designed system to handle even two physical processors. Systems that can support many physical CPU chips require all kinds of special hardware support to make it efficient: [crossbar switching fabrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbar_switch), [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) schemes, etc.